# A cartoon where a necklace turns into a pegasus and a ring turns into a tiger?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Main character is blonde and in an episode someone stole the necklace and harmed it. I watched this on Disney Channel, or maybe Clan? In spain and like, at least 5 years ago. No clue about the names but the main character had the necklace that turns into a pegasus, a brown headed girl I think had a ring turn into a tiger or something like that, and there was a third person with another animal which I can't remember. Please help

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Princess Starla and the Jewel Riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Gwenevere_and_the_Jewel_Riders). The princess has a pegasus, the queen and king have tigers, the boys from the forest have wolves, and possibly other characters have other animals. Although I'd be a bit surprised if this was broadcast on Disney Channel five years ago. It's a series from the 90s.